# Question about setting up my input feature array for training an LSTM classifier to take past observations into account

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am trying to understand how to set up an LSTM with keras for a time series binary classification problem. I have set up a sample LSTM example, but it doesn't seem to be picking up information from prior observations. I think that my current approach is only using the feature data from the current observation.

Below is my standalone demo code.

My question is this: for an LSTM to pick up the pattern from previous observations, do I need to define a sliding window so that each observation actually includes the data from the the previous observations that comprise the sliding window period, or does keras get those itself from the features array?

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# this section just generates some sample data
# the pattern we are trying to pick up on is that
# shift_value number of observations prior to a True
# label, the features are always [.5, .5, .5]

shift_value = 5
n_examples = 10000

features = []
labels = []
random.seed(1)

# create the labels
for i in range(n_examples + shift_value):
    labels.append(random.choice([True, False]))

# create the features
for label in labels:
    if label:
        features.append([.5, .5, .5]) 
    else:
        feature_1 = random.random()
        feature_2 = random.random()
        feature_3 = random.random()
        features.append([feature_1, feature_2, feature_3])

df = pd.DataFrame(features)
df['label'] = labels
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'label']
df['label'] = df['label'].shift(5)
df = df.dropna()

features_array = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].values
labels_array = df[['label']].values

# reshape the data

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(features_array, labels_array, test_size = .1, shuffle=False)

X_train_reshaped = np.reshape(X_train, (len(X_train), 1, X_train.shape[1]))
X_test_reshaped = np.reshape(X_test, (len(X_test), 1, X_train.shape[1]))

encoder = LabelEncoder()
Y_train_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(Y_train)
Y_test_encoded  = encoder.fit_transform(Y_test)

# define and run the model

neurons = 10
batch_size = 100
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(neurons, 
               batch_input_shape=(batch_size,
                                  X_train_reshaped.shape[1], 
                                  X_train_reshaped.shape[2] 
                                  ),
               activation = 'sigmoid',
               stateful = False)
               )

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train_reshaped, 
          Y_train_encoded, 
          validation_data=(X_test_reshaped, Y_test_encoded), 
          epochs=10, 
          batch_size=batch_size)
```

The above example never converges, and I don't think it's taking prior observations into account at all. It should be able to find the basic pattern of 5 observations prior to a True is always [.5, .5, .5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a sequence to sequence problem. Think of this learning problem as below

> Given a sequence of length `seq_length` if the input at time step `t` is `[0.5,0.5,0.5]` then the output at `t+shift_value == 1`
>   else `t+shift_value == 0`

To model this learning problem, you will use an LSTM which will unroll `seq_length` times and each time step will take an input of size `3`. Also each timestep has a corresponding output of size `1` (correspoiding to True of False). This is depicted as below:

[image]

Code:

```
import random
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM

shift_value = 5
seq_length = 50

def generate_data(n, shift_value, seq_length):
    X = np.random.rand(n, seq_length, 3)
    Y = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(n, seq_length))
    for j in range(len(Y)):
        for i in range(shift_value,len(Y[j])):
            if Y[j][i] == 1:
                X[j][i-shift_value] = np.array([0.5,0.5,0.5])
    return X, Y.reshape(n,seq_length, 1)

# Generate Train and Test Data
X_train, Y_train = generate_data(9000,shift_value,seq_length)
X_test, Y_test = generate_data(100,shift_value,seq_length)

# Train the model
neurons = 32
batch_size = 100
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(neurons, 
               batch_input_shape=(batch_size, seq_length, 3),
               activation = 'relu',
               stateful = False,
               return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, 
          Y_train,
          validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), 
          epochs=30, 
          batch_size=batch_size)
```

Output (Filtered):

```
...
Epoch 30/30
9000/9000 [=========] - loss: 0.1650 - acc: 0.9206 - val_loss: 0.1362 - val_acc: 0.9324
```

In 30 epochs it reached validation acc of 93%. Even though it is a deterministic function, the model will never be 100% accurate because of ambiguity within the first `shift_value` labels.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response with the working example. This is an interesting approach to treat it as a sequence problem. Most of the examples I've seen for time series treat it as a classification problem and use "return_sequences=False" in the model. What I do gather from your solution is that I need to manually pass the features and labels into the model by building arrays that contain the lagged features and labels. This was very useful, thank you.

Comment: @Solving it via classification is tricky because you want the model to learn the sequence. You can model it as binary classification problem if you are interested  in the label of only the last state of the sequence (set  return_sequences to false).  In such a case your model will learn if the input at last-shift_value step == [0.5,0.5,0.5] or not.